# JAVA How to compare integer using compareTo in this exercise

Tags: java, compareto

I'm trying to do this exercise: i have a student that has a name,surname and a number, i want to order the students by number..if i want to order by name or surname it seems easy but with number i don't know how to do..
this is my code:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
private String name;
private String surname;
private int number;


public Student(String n, String s, int m) {
    name = n;
    surname = s;
    number = m;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getmatricola() {
    return number;
}
//CompareTo Name
public int compareTo(Student otherObject) {
    return name.compareTo(otherObject.getName());
}
}
//TESTER
 ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>(); 
 System.out.print("\n ORDER BY NUMBER \n");

    Collections.sort(list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Student s = list.get(i);
        String std = s.getAll();
        System.out.println(std);


    }
```

Comment: It's actually easier to compare by numbers.

Comment: [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like:

```
public int compareTo(Student otherObject) {
    return Integer.compare(this.number, otherObject.getNumber());
}
```

Comment: if i want to implements both compareTo for number and compareTo for name how i can do to differentiate them when I call the method?

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo you cannot do that. A `class` can only `extends` one instance of a generic interface, due to type erasure. You will have to use an external `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

So why you number is an int you can substract the number and return the difference:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
private String name;
private String surname;
private int number;


public Student(String n, String s, int m) {
    name = n;
    surname = s;
    number = m;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getmatricola() {
    return number;
}
//CompareTo number
public int compareTo(Student otherObject) {
    return number - otherObject.getmatricola();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a **very** common bug, comparing with minus can overflow. Don't do it, it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: @BoristheSpider can you add an example please.

Comment: try comparing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I can see no problem if i compare these values. So in this case the number will be always positive. Thats why i think you example will be theoretical.

Comment: @Jens Try `i=-2147483648` and `j=1`. `Integer.compare(i, j)` will return `-1` while `i - j` returns `2147483647`. The sign changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this...should work
        //CompareTo Name
        public int compareTo(Student otherObject) {
          if( this.getmatricola() > otherObject.getmatricola()) 
                                return 1;
          else
                return -1;
        }